# self.tabBarItem.title not working?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

In my iPhone application, I have a tab bar. This tab bar holds a UINavigationController. I have:

- In Interface Builder set the tab item title to 'Create New'
- In the UINavigation controller I have `self.tabBarItem.title = 'Create New';` and `self.title = 'Create New';`
- In the UIViewController pushed onto the controller: self.tabBarItem.title = 'Create New'; but `self.title = 'Blah';`.

But, always, the self.title of the first view controller pushed onto the navigation controller is shown (Blah). How would you set the title of the tab bar item? Thanks,
Isaac Waller

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found if I used `self.navigationItem.title = 'Blah';` instead of `self.title`, it would work.

Comment: Yes. Both the TabBarItem and the NavigationBar inherites self.title. However, for some reason, the title cannot be changed for the TabBarItem, only the NavigationItem. It's weird. Also, self.title should be set before the navigationItem.title. Just FYI :)

Answer (score 18):

I just solved the same issue. I was using `self.tabBarItem.item` for the 1st tab of my `tabBarController`, which is the first and only one that loads its `navigationController`. So for the first tab in a tab bar you have to set the title differently. I'll try to illustrate:

**tab bar with 3 tabs** (a `UINavigationController` provides content each tab)

1. tab 1

   - loads tab1NavController.m (sets `self.tabBarItem.item` to '1st')
   - loads tab1ViewController.m (sets `self.title` to 'tab1 View'
2. tab 2

   - loads tab2NavController.m (sets `self.tabBarItem.item` to '2nd')
   - loads tab2ViewController.m (sets `self.title` to 'tab View'
3. tab 3

   - loads tab3NavController.m (sets `self.tabBarItem.item` to '3rd')
   - loads tab3ViewController.m (sets `self.title` to 'tab3 View'

When the tab bar loads all of its `viewControllers` for each of the 3 tabs, the tab buttons in the tab bar have these labels:

1. 'tab1 View'
2. '2nd'
3. '3rd'

This is because the 2nd and 3rd nav controllers aren't loaded until the user selects those tabs. The 1st tab is loaded when the `UITabBarController` is loaded and due to the order of events it replaces the `tabBarItem.title` with the navController's rootViewController's `self.title`.

### Solution

To fix this, you simply use `self.navigationItem.title` instead of `self.title`. You ONLY have to do this for the 1st tab's navController's rootViewController.

I hope that makes sense. You did solve your own problem, but I wanted you and anyone else to know WHY it works like this.