# UITabBar + UINavigationBar conflict title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBar and a UINavigationBar created in IB, when I launch my application everytime I navigate the UINavigation title change because I'm using

```
self.title = @"NAME";
```

my problem is that the UITabBarItem will change with the same name at the same time.
 I want to put a static name only for the UITabBarItem, how to do it in IB or programatically maybe.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution in this adress [Stackoverflow navigationItem Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717844/self-tabbaritem-title-not-working) Sorry I didn't find it before posting my question.

Answer (score 1):

try returning an explicit tabBarItem for your controller, and set its title yourself.

```
- (UITabBarItem *) tabBarItem {
    return [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle: ...
```

Comment: good idea no error when I build but its not working, any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

try this, in your viewDidLoad

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = @"title";
```