# decouple tabbaritems from viewcontroller title

Tags: iphone

We are looking for a way to decouple the lower UITabBar from the titles of the current view controller.

When the title of the view controller changes, we want the text in the tabbaritem to remain the same.

Is there way to achieve this other than having to reset the value in each view?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717844/self-tabbaritem-title-not-working) I found the solution (had the same problem): specify the table view controller title **before** the tab bar item title. An example from my app:

```
routesTableViewController.title = @"Routes";
routesController.tabBarItem.title = @"Schedule";
```